# Does CiviRules add/remove a contact to a Group based on Membership starting/expiring

Tags: civirules

Haven't used CiviRules before and I see it is only listed as working on 4.4 - but I want to see if on 4.6 can it

- add a contact to a Group when they purchase a new Membership,
- remove them from a Group when their Membership expires
- act on only specified Membership types

Comment: Is the triggering 'event' membership added, or rather contribution added (of the financial type membership)? This could give two very different routes to solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Pete, we have not worked on any conditions for membership status. We never had (and never will :-)) have the ambition of creating all sorts of Conditions. We have created the engine and the conditions/actions that our projects need. However, the engine allows you to create your own conditions and actions quite easily, that is documented on our wiki: http://redmine.civicoop.org/projects/civirules/wiki

Documentation pages on creating conditions:
http://redmine.civicoop.org/projects/civirules/wiki/Tutorial_create_a_new_and_simple_condition
http://redmine.civicoop.org/projects/civirules/wiki/Tutorial_create_a_more_complicated_condition_with_its_own_form_processing
It should be a pretty easy job to add a condition for membership type or membership status.

Comment: looking forward to exploring it ;-)

Comment: Actually i got a hint here http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/does-civirules-add-remove-a-contact-to-a-group-based-on-membership-starting-expi/6836 that the " field value comparison" might suffice. And indeed it does offer me Membership Status, but also a warning "Error. The field 'id' has no associated option list." Will see if fixing that is enough.

Comment: Yes, that should work. But I guess it would be really good if there was a condition 'membership status' and type as I reckon there will be other potential users that might be a little less savvy?

Comment: The linked sites are not available any more, but documentation about custom conditions can be found here: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-condition/

Answer (score 2):

I will add to this as I explore, but first up my findings.

There is an 'event' for

- membership is added
- membership is changed

There is an 'action' for "add to group" which allows adding to single or multiple groups.

AFAIK there is no Condition yet for
 - Membership type
 - membership status change

Also checked out if I could make the Rule based on the Activity that is generated when someone Expires eg 
 - Activity Type = Change Membership Status
 - Activity Subject = Status changed from Grace to Expired

While the former exists, the latter doesn't so I can't see that I can currently build the Rule off that.

So either way looks like we need to add some new Conditions. Will update on progress

Comment: There should be a generic condition called field value comparison. I haven't tried that for membership, but I am using that for contribution status, which should be similar. So, if 'field value comparison' is available for a 'event' of the membership entity, then select membership status field, and select value

Comment: Great hint thank you. While membership status is on the list, it comes with a warning "Error The field 'id' has no associated option list." and while the dropdown shows the names of the status, saving and reopening suggests it isn't quite working as it keeps reverting to "New'. Will dig more

Comment: Any progress Pete? Happy to create a membership type and membership status condition at the sprint after London CiviCon (but perhaps you guys are already doing just that)?

Comment: I have just added the Membership Type and Membership Status conditions to the latest version of CiviRules.

Comment: Look forward to giving it a try. Many thanks.

Comment: This looks to work really well. Thank you